# Mouseup/down on two different elements within a jQuery click delegate cancels the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a clickable item, which contains child elements, too. My problem stems from wanting to animate the :active state of the clicked item by using a 1px translation.

1. The mousedown of the click lands on a child element
2. The 1px translate *moves the child element from under the mouse pointer*
3. The mouseup event now happens on the parent element

This results in the click getting canceled. I can prevent the child element from catching the click using `pointer-events: none` in CSS, but since it's both new and unstable, I'd love to find a more compatible fix. For now, I've settled on just sticking a transparent DIV on top of the whole item, but that's ugly.

Exaggareted demo in this pen: http://codepen.io/JonFabritius/pen/mJuzy

Try clicking the bottom half of the orange bar, the pointer remains on top of the child element. Then click on the top half, which causes the element to move from under the pointer.

It's probably staring me in the face, but I haven't been able to find a simple fix- any ideas appreciated.

Comment: The answer is probably _don't do move click targets out from under the pointer_. You describe a 1px transition, but your demo features a 12px transition. 1px won't cause a problem unless someone clicks right on the edge, which seems unlikely. Is this a real problem?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that and decided there must be a way :) It happens surprisingly often, since the clickable discussion forum item contains a number of children, such as a discussion title, post metadata, user avatars etc.

Comment: And to be precise, the click target is *the parent*, which doesn't get moved from under the pointer, but an annoying child element of the designated click delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I don't jQuery.

This is a response better considered as a comment, though with the addition of code.

You say that "the click target is *the parent*" - Sorry to be a little thick here, but when you say it's the click target, is the *parent* the element that has the event listener attached to it, or by `click target`, do you mean that it is the value returned by evt.target? (Where evt is the single variable passed to the event handling function)

To better illustrate what I'm getting at, consider the following code:

**JS portion:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    document.getElementById('clickTarget').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}

function handleClick(evt)
{
    console.log(this.id + ': is the id of the "this" element');
    console.log(evt.target.id + ": was the id of the evt.target");
}
```

**HTML portion:**

```
<body>
    <div id='clickTarget'><a id='link1'>Link1</a><a id='link2'>Link2</a></div>
</body>
```

Now then, when you click on `link1`, the output shown in the console is:

```
clickTarget: is the id of the "this" element
link1: was the id of the evt.target
```

Predictably, clicking on `link2` shows the following:

```
clickTarget: is the id of the "this" element
link2: was the id of the evt.target
```

So, you can clearly see that in this example, the `<div>` is the parent of the two `<a>` elements.
Yet, in each instance the target is different - it's not the parent, it's the actual element that was clicked.

You've used jQuery, which, while simple to add functionality, hides implementation details, slows JS execution and (usually) adds unnecessarily to page-weight. Your code is very short and sweet, yet what is being returned requires some investigation - it's certainly not obvious.

As a side note, a quick look at the jQuery Docs: [jQuery .delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) tells us that as of jQuery 1.7, the preferred method use to achieve this functionality is `.on()` - it's likely of no consequence, but one never knows..

Comment: jQuery is fast to implement and has worked well and fast across multiple platforms in my projects, so its my comfort zone.

But this case is a good motivator for me to try to step out and actually spend some time looking at JavaScript in more depth, thanks. The issue remains; when a mousedown takes place on top of a different element than the mouseup, it doesn't constitute a click. And perhaps that's just it- it defies the definition of what a click is supposed to be, technically. UI- wise, however, things look different. And that, I guess, is why the css `pointer-events` exists.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Turns out if you use the current `.on` syntax, it works fine:</s>

<s>$(function() {
        // target ON event, delegate
        $('#container').on('click', '.item', function() {
            $('.item').append('*');
        });
    });</s>

**UPDATE** Could you do this with a custom class? This seems to work so long as the pointer doesn't leave the `.item` element. Child elements behave as expected.

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').on('mousedown', '.item', function() {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.item').append('*');
  }).on('mouseup', '.item', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

});
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lponk

Comment: No, I tested this with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, and the issue remains; clicking on the top part of the orange bar results in no click, while clicking on the bottom triggers one. Keep an eye on when the orange bar escapes from under the mouse pointer, before mouse up.

Comment: Is it necessary that you use the `:active` pseudo-class, or could you apply/remove a custom class? See my update; also updated the pen.

Comment: The :active class is conveniently associated with a click. Your example opens up the touch-scroll can of worms, as I'd also have to check for movement on touch devices. I'm already using a bit of code to on the actual site to eliminate the 300ms touch double-tap wait, so I might just need to write my own click handler, based on mouseup/down as in your example :)